# How to call form filed ajax function if input field meets maximum 8 characters in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I tried to trigger Ajax callback function, when textfield user input meets 8 characters using keyup event. But Ajax callback triggering when user enter first character itself.

I tried setting minimum length in textfield and i thought ajax call will happen after met minimum length, but not working.

```
            $form['mobile_no'] = array (
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#name' => 'mobile_no',
            '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => [$this,'verifyNumber'],
            'event' => 'keyup'
            ]);
```

I expect the textfield Ajax call should happen when user enters minimum of 8 characters in textfield.

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible that easy, but you could use the change event `'event' => 'change',` and then add a max length `'#maxlegth' => 8,`. In your `verifyNumber` function then you could check if the number leghth equals 8. I hope this helps as a workaround. Otherways there is a Drupal Forum, where you can ask specific Drupal questions: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: working fine, but i want to set minimum and maximum 8 characters.